# DynamoDB Python 2.7 Lambda function - remove item from list

Tags: python-2.7, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have a "users" table, each one has a user name (the key value) and a **list** of items (each one represented by ID, a number).

I wrote a function for adding an item with a given ID to the list.

Now, I want to delete a given item from the list. Meaning, given the ID and the user name, I want to delete this item from the user's list. I already tried using the "update_item" function with an "UpdateExpression" and using "REMOVE", but it only accepts int as an index and not a variable.

I tried multiple solutions, with no success.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.